# Is there way to split dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is the dictionary framed in python.

```
risk = {'Main' : {'Cat1' : [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']],'Cat2' : [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']],'Cat3' : [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'],['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]}}
```

Is there a way to split it like below

```
risk1

{'Main': {'Cat1': [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']]}}
```

```
risk2

{'Main': {'Cat2': [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']]}}
```

```
risk3

{'Main': {'Cat3': [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No need to iterate over the dict.**

```
risk = {
    'Main': {
        'Cat1': [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']],
        'Cat2': [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']],
        'Cat3': [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]
    }
}
```

`risk['Main']['Cat1']` accesses the value associated with the key 'Cat1' within the dictionary associated with the key 'Main' in the risk dictionary. You can create the new dicts as follow:

```
risk1 = {'Main': {'Cat1': risk['Main']['Cat1']}}
risk2 = {'Main': {'Cat2': risk['Main']['Cat2']}}
risk3 = {'Main': {'Cat3': risk['Main']['Cat3']}}


print("risk1\n", risk1)
print("risk2\n", risk2)
print("risk3\n", risk3)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
risk1
 {'Main': {'Cat1': [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']]}}

risk2
 {'Main': {'Cat2': [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']]}}

risk3
 {'Main': {'Cat3': [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `for` comprehension such as

```
res = [ {'Main': {k: v}} for (k, v) in risk['Main'].items() ]
```

for extracting each entry in the dictionary, where each tuple `(k, v)` delivered from `items()` is converted into a dictionary key-value `{k: v}`. Hence

```
for xs in res:
    print(xs)

{'Main': {'Cat1': [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']]}}
{'Main': {'Cat2': [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']]}}
{'Main': {'Cat3': [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
risk = {
    'Main': {
        'Cat1': [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']],
        'Cat2': [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']],
        'Cat3': [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]
    }
}

split_risk = [{'Main': {category: data}} for category, data in risk['Main'].items()]

# Print the split risk dictionaries
for idx, split_dict in enumerate(split_risk, start=1):
    print(f'risk{idx}\n{split_dict}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to create discrete variables. That's not an extensible solution. A better approach is to use a dictionary. Something like this:

```
risk = {'Main' : {'Cat1' : [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']],'Cat2' : [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']],'Cat3' : [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'],['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]}}

d = {}

for i, (k, v) in enumerate(risk['Main'].items(), 1):
    d[f'risk{i}'] = {'Main': {k: v}}

# then, for example...
print(d['risk3'])
```

**Output:**

```
{'Main': {'Cat3': [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the variable names to be `risk1`, `risk2` and `risk3`. It's not a scalable solution. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) SO post for details. I'd use @DarkKnight's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76919228/19716381), but if you really want the variables to be named as above, you can use tuple unpacking to get the variables as desired.

```py
risk = {'Main': {'Cat1': [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1']],
                 'Cat2': [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']],
                 'Cat3': [['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4'], ['A5', 'B5', 'C5', 'D5']]}}

risks = []

for k, v in risk['Main'].items():
    risk_tmp = {'Main': {k: v}}
    risks.append(risk_tmp)

risk1, risk2, risk3 = tuple(risks)

print(risk1)
print(risk2)
print(risk3)
```

To get the variable names as `risk{n}`, you can use a separate script to generate the variable names, copy and paste it into code. Again, **I really don't recommend this**, but here is a sample script if you really need to.

```py
p = [f"risk{i}" for i in range(1, 11)]
for i in p:
    print(i, end=", ")
print()
```